# ZoomingPDFViewer crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pdf, crash

Hi I'm running ZoomingPDFViewer sample code from apple but the app crash with following warning.

> ZoomingPDFViewer[1557:280734] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFScrollView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10101b200'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I'm using xcode 8.2 right now.

When update DataViewController method viewdidload the app is running but pdf is not shown why I don't know.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _scrollView=[[PDFScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage( self.pdf, self.pageNumber );
    NSLog(@"self.page==NULL? %@",self.page==NULL?@"yes":@"no");

    if( self.page != NULL ) CGPDFPageRetain( self.page );
    [self.scrollView setPDFPage:self.page];
}
```

Please help if some one knows.

Thanks

Comment: Check setPDFPage method. their could be issue due to self.page value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed . I create a new project and replaced files from sample code (pdfZoomViewer) and initialize  our start view controller set in storyboard same as in sample. Make sure that your  outlet connection is connected from storyboard .